# PowerShell Set GetListDefaultResultSize Value

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, exchange-server

I have an Exchange Server and would like to make settings there from the IIS (Manager) via PowerShell. (About the GUI it takes too long)

`SERVERNAME\Sites\Exchange Back End\ecp -> Application Settings -> GetListDefaultResultSize`

I want a PowerShell command that adds `GetListDefaultResultSize` if it doesn't exist (and if it exists) sets the value.

I tried this PowerShell Command (Unfortunately this one did not work) :
`Set-ECPVirtualDirectory -GetListDefaultResultSize 2000`

Comment: Try this `Set-EcpVirtualDirectory -Identity "SERVERNAME\ecp" -GetListDefaultResultSize 2000`.  Also, you need to run these commands with proper administrator privileges.